# try and catch in PHP - should I return in the 'try' block?

Tags: php, try-catch

Below is my `try catch` statement in a function. I have not used try catch statement much, and I wanted to know how to return values in a try catch statement. Should I return a value after the try and catch statement or is returning in the try block OK?

```
function createBucket($bucket_name) {
    if ($this->isValidBucketName($bucket_name)) {
        if ($this->doesBucketExist($bucket_name)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            try {
                $this->s3Client->createBucket(
                        array(
                            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
                            'ACL' => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ
                        // Add more items if required here
                ));
                return true;
            }
            catch (S3Exception $e) {
                $this->airbrake->notifyOnException($e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->airbrake->notifyOnError('invalid bucket name');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? This is absolutely fine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> is returning in the try block OK?

Yes, it is. If you need to return the value there, do it.

```
try {
  function_that_throws_exception();
  return true;   // <-- This will never happen if an exception is raised

}
catch(Exception $e){

}
```

Comment: Thanks i was just confused if it would be returned even if exception was raised

Comment: @askkirati: Watch out for returning in a `finally` block - that might behave strangely

Comment: @eric PHP doesn't have finally clause :)

Comment: @Jack: [Oh, really?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) As of 5.5, it does.